# Why was the germ theory of disease held in disdain?

Tags: medicine

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_theory_of_disease), the germ theory of disease has been held in disdain for centuries in Europe, where the miasma theory was prevalent.

Why were scientists so biased against the germ theory?

Comment: Because of Galen's authority, it says it in the same sentence. Galen gave a comprehensive picture of how the body functions and diseases develop based on four humors, existing practice of medicine relied on it. Without replacing the whole thing suggestions about germs did not fit.

Comment: A precursor to Germ Theory, Ignaz Semmelweis advocated for hand washing after discovering that hand-washing with a solution of chlorinated lime reduced the incidence of fatal childbed fever tenfold in maternity institutions.  His wiki article states, "The rejection of Semmelweis's empirical observations is often traced to belief perseverance, the psychological tendency of clinging to discredited beliefs. Also, some historians of science argue that resistance to path-breaking contributions of obscure scientists is common and 'constitutes the single most formidable block to scientific advances."